# Minimal cuts vs Edge connectivity

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-cut

Here is a question asking the connection between the edge connectivity of a graph and its minimal cuts.

As we know, the edge connectivity of an undirected graph is the minimum number `k` of edges that must be removed to disconnect the graph. For example, the edge connectivity of a tree is 1, and the edge connectivity of a cycle is 2.

My thought is that the capacity of the minimal cuts should be equal to the edge connectivity. Because a cut is to separate a graph into two disconnect parts. If we know the edge connectivity `k`, it means that we have to remove or cut off at least `k` edges to make the graph into two disconnect parts. Therefore the capacity of minimal cuts should be `k`.

I haven't found any conclusion or proof about this question, so I ask here. Could anyone check if my thought is correct or give me any other idea on it?

Comment: Minimal in which sense? Cut the minimum number of edges to get two disjoint subsets?

Comment: @jweyrich Yes I think, since it's undirected graph in the question and no specific weights are assigned to the edges.

Comment: To my understanding, the concept of a cut is related to network problems, which means that in addition to the graph itself, a source node `s` and a terminal node `t` must be specified, and the notion is actually an `s`-`t`-cut; I assume that the notions are related, but not directly compatible.

Comment: @Codor Yes, it's related to network flow problem, since I found the edge connectivity can be determined by running Ford-Falkerson Algorithm, which is to find the maximum flow in a network.